# how display every similar rows in separate table?

Tags: php, sql

i'm creating a table that receive orders from users, the C_ID will store in (StationaryCustomersInfo) table where the C_ID is unique, and the table (StationaryOrders) will store every item with the C_ID, the C_ID in (StationaryOrders) table is not unique because C_ID will repeated with every items belongs to that C_ID.

i want to display every orders by the C_ID where every orders for each customer will displayed with separate table.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Item, Personal, Department, Quantity, Color FROM StationaryOrders, StationaryCustomersInfo WHERE StationaryCustomersInfo.C_ID = StationaryOrders.C_ID");

?>
<table align="center" border='3' style="width:60%; line-height:30px; border-color: #020B58;">
      <tr>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Personal</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      </tr>

          <?php
    if($sql){

           while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
               ?>

      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Item']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Personal']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Color']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
          }
    }

    ?>

</table>
```

I expect to display each customers orders with separate table and button belongs to that table.

Comment: `FROM StationaryOrders, StationaryCustomersInfo` this way to join tables is deprecated since about 25 years. Please consider using proper [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: i don't want to join tables, i want to display every repeated rows with separate tables

Comment: This is what your query is (badly) doing

Comment: the table that is stored in (StationaryCustomersInfo) is to make the ordering to the customers who is registered only.
so i just want to display every customer order with his/her own table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by adding in your query the `C_ID` and sort the result by `C_ID`. Then, in php, you can check if the previous fetch `C_ID` is the same than the current one.

In example :

```
// Let's factorise the building of the <table> header there to avoid duplication in code
function ShowTableHeader($cid)
{
    ?>
<table align="center" border='3' style="width:60%; line-height:30px; border-color: #020B58;">
      <caption>Orders of user <?php echo $cid; ?> : </caption>
      <tr>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Personal</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      </tr>
    <?php
}

$query = "SELECT sci.C_ID, "
        .       "Item, "
        .       "Personal, "
        .       "Department, "
        .       "Quantity, "
        .       "Color "
        ."FROM StationaryOrders so "
        ."LEFT JOIN StationaryCustomersInfo sci "
        ."ON sci.C_ID = so.C_ID "
        ."ORDER BY sci.C_ID";

$sql = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if ($sql)
{
    if ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        // initialize the first C_ID for the first result
        $previousCID = $row['C_ID'];
        ShowTableHeader($previousCID);
        do
        {
            // different C_ID than before ? Let's build a new <table>
            if ($previousCID != $row['C_ID'])
            {
                echo "</table>";
                $previousCID = $row['C_ID'];
                ShowTableHeader($previousCID);
            }
            ?>
      <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Item']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Personal']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Department']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Quantity']; ?></td>
      <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['Color']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
        } while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql));
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows every customers orders with missing one order of each customer

Comment: @RawanAlshaik found my error. I edited the answer removing the `else`